# Difference between satisfy and fulfill

Tags: word-choice, word-difference

Writing a mathematical text I came across a [site](https://www.cadmo.ethz.ch/education/thesis/rules.pdf) that lists some *common mistakes* when writing scientific texts in English including the following:

> <s>x fulfills property P</s>
>      x satisfies property P

I am now very confused since I read this (the “wrong” usage) quite a few times in various papers (and I can't remember a single one were the “correct” word is used). I also found [this site](http://wikidiff.com/satisfy/fulfill) stating

> The difference between satisfy and fulfill is that satisfy is to […] fulfill (wishes, requirements) […]
>
> fulfill: […] To satisfy, carry out, bring to completion (an obligation, a requirement, etc.).

which gives me headache explaining *satisfy* with *fulfill* and vice versa.

So what is the difference between *satisfy* and *fulfill*? In particular I want to know what to use when I want to express that a condition must be *satisfied / fulfilled*?

The specific examples where I want to use one of these words:

1. The angles *satisfy / fulfill* the condition…
2. The vectors *satisfy / fulfill* the inequalities…
3. This condition has to be *satisfied / fulfilled* for every vertex.

I don't think these are very different, but just in case. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, this seems to have little to do with dictionary definitions and more to do with what is *customary* in the field -- which means it's less about understanding *why* and more about memorizing *what* is most common.  There is no reason why *satisfy* is correct and *fulfill* is not, other than "this is how it's done".

Comment: But _satisfy_ **is** “how it's done” – at least in the above examples?

Comment: @spettekaka: Then what's your problem? If you know how a certain word is used, you know how it's used. Are you saying this bothers you beyond that?

Comment: @Robusto My point is that I am not entirely sure what to use in my cases (1–3). Do both just work fine? Is the author of the first quotation right, i. e. is _fulfill_ wrong usage? For me, _fulfill_ feels fine – a feeling that I got from different papers using it, while I am not aware of one using _satisfy_. What should I use?

Comment: I would use *satisfy* for all three of your examples. You won't be misunderstood. If you are talking about predictions, you may use *fulfill*.

Comment: Language-wise, *satisfy* meets certain conditions, while *fulfill* meets all conditions. As this is strictly a math context, you might ask this on [*Mathematics SE*](https://math.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 4):

*Satisfy* has these two Latin words as a root (from Google):

> late Middle English: from Old French satisfier, formed irregularly from Latin satisfacere ‘to content,’ from satis ‘enough’ + facere ‘make.’

whereas *fulfill* has this etymology:

> late Old English fullfyllan ‘fill up, make full’ (see full1, fill).

When something is full, putting more in will make it overflow.

So *satisfy* implies that there is a minimum to consider good, but you could do more to improve things further than the minimum.

*Fulfill* implies that either you achieved a standard (reached the "full" line") or did not.  There is really no such thing as "halfway fulfilled," for example.

This is why things like destinies or orders are fulfilled, but not satisfied.  Either you reached your destiny or you didn't, either your order is complete or it is not. But you could satisfy an indignant customer who didn't get an order fulfilled by giving him/her a gift card, though a higher amount gift card would make him/her more satisfied.

Comment: Nice answer, thanks. So with this I think _fulfill_ is the better variant for my examples, since all conditions should be _fulfilled_ and not just some. Or what do you think? I am still not 100 % sure.

Comment: Then, speaking about a doctoral thesis... Would you say "authorizes for submission since it fulfils the conditions necessary for its defence" or "satisfies"?